# LeetCode 05 with Manacher's algorithm

Tags: performance, algorithm, kotlin

I finished LeetCode 05 with simplified (for ease of implementation) [Manacher's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_palindromic_substring#Manacher%27s_algorithm). IMHO it should keeps \$\mathcal{O}(n)\$ time and space complexity. However, LeetCode's benchmark ranked my solution as worst 5% and 30%.  What causes such poor performance (time and space)? Can anybody help me diagnose where it went wrong?

Description:

> Given a string s, return the longest palindromic substring in s.

Example:

```
Input: s = "babad"  
Output: "bab"  
Note: "aba" is also a valid answer.
```

Code:

```kotlin
data class LimitInfo(var center: Int, var rightMost: Int)

class Solution {
    fun longestPalindrome(s: String): String {
        val newS = s.fold("#") { acc, c -> "$acc$c#" }
        val radii = MutableList(newS.length) { 0 }
        val limitInfo = LimitInfo(0, 0)

        fun symRadius(center: Int, checkedRadius: Int): Int {
            var radius = checkedRadius + 1
            while (newS.getOrNull(center - radius)?.equals(newS.getOrNull(center + radius)) == true) radius += 1
            return radius - 1
        }

        newS.indices.forEach { center ->
            val space = limitInfo.rightMost - center
            val checkedRadius = when {
                space < 0 -> 0
                else -> minOf(radii[limitInfo.center * 2 - center], space)
            }

            val radius = symRadius(center, checkedRadius)

            radii[center] = radius

            if (center + radius > limitInfo.rightMost) {
                limitInfo.rightMost = center + radius
                limitInfo.center = center
            }

        }

        val res = radii.withIndex().maxBy { it.value }!!.let { (loc, radius) ->
            newS.slice(loc - radius..loc + radius)
        }.filterIndexed { index, _ -> index % 2 == 1 }
        return res
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the way you're folding it to create `newS` is \$\mathcal{O}(n^2)\$. Try instead:

```
val newS = buildString { 
  append('#')
  s.forEach { append(it).append('#') } 
}
```

Also consider that most respondents are probably inputting \$\mathcal{O}(n)\$ solutions, so smaller optimizations that don't affect big O might make a big difference in your percentile. For example, using an `IntArray` instead of `MutableList`, manually iterating instead of boxing with `withIndex()`, eliminating the unnecessary intermediate LimitInfo class, checking indices and using `get()` instead of `getOrNull()`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

At least in the worst case you can get \$\mathcal{O}(n^2)\$. For some strings (like 'aaaaaaaaa') any substring is going to be symmetric. That's why `symRadius` function may take \$\mathcal{O}(n)\$. So in worst case `symRadius` is called with \$\mathcal{O}(n)\$ complexity for all \$n\$ chars (which should lead to \$\mathcal{O}(n^2)\$ in total).

Comment: But the biggest performance issue indeed should be related to string concatenation in the fold. As already mentioned @Tenfour04.

Comment: In my logic, `symRadius` accepts `checkedRadius` as starting point for further checks. In your example, except for first several 'a', `symRadius` will get pretty big initial `checkedRadius` from `radii`, since preventing square complexity. is it right?
BTW, I suppose it as linear since `rightMost` keeps going rightward, no very strict but intuitive inference.